# Sorting multiple text inside curly braces

Tags: javascript

I have a string from which I need to sort the texts.

My string would be like

```
    .x{bbc:aa;abc:123;}
    .y{xyz:40;len:12;ccd:ab;}
```

I need the output sorted like

```
    .x{abc:123;bbc:aa;}
    .y{ccd:ab;len:12;xyz:40;}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This works!

I've made a function for you:

```
function sortarray(str) {
            var s = str;
            var insideCurly = /{.*}/g.exec(s)[0].replace(/[{}]/g, '').replace(/;$/, '');
            var arr = insideCurly.split(';');
            return s.replace(/{.*}/, "{" + arr.sort().join(';') + ";}");
        }
```

Call it like this:

```
var sortedString= sortarray(".x{bbc:aa;abc:123;}"); // returns .x{abc:123;bbc:aa;}
```

Live demo:<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/NWvyE/1</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. But how about multiple items, like 
       .x{bbc:123;abc:aa;} 
       .a{zbc:123;cbc:aa;}

Comment: use an array and do it. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer ;)